# Chmod 644 on /etc/ any way to fix?

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

I tried to tab complete something and I guess it wasnt there. I know you are not supposed to set the permissions to /etc/ like that, but my permissions seem to be all messed up. whoami prints out cannot find name for user ID 1002 and I cannot cd into /etc/ anymore. passwd and shadow use 640 and 644 so I am not sure why this is a problem. Regardless, is there any way to fix this?

The command run was `sudo chmod 644 /etc/`

```
I have no name!@vpn-server:/$ whoami
whoami: cannot find name for user ID 1002


I have no name!@vpn-server:/$ cd etc
bash: cd: etc: Permission denied

I have no name!@vpn-server:/$ ls -al etc
d????????? ? ? ? ?                ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?                ? ..
d????????? ? ? ? ?                ? acpi
-????????? ? ? ? ?                ? adduser.conf

I have no name!@vpn-server:/$ sudo su
sudo: can't open /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  What exactly is the problem?  Did someone type `chmod 644 /etc`?  Did they add a `-R` in there as well?  What happened specifically?

Comment: there was no -R. The command was: sudo chmod 644 /etc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off all your question is unclear. but still see this...

your `/etc` directory permission is `644` ie:`chmod 644 /etc/`

To change Directory **execute** permission is required

That's why you are getting this error

> I have no name!@vpn-server:/$ cd etc
>
> bash: cd: etc: Permission denied

so change the permission to `chmod 755 /etc`

2nd thing `ls -al` showing this type of output (`d????????? ? ? ? ?`) because

```
I have no name!@vpn-server:/$ ls -al etc
d????????? ? ? ? ?                ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?                ? ..
d????????? ? ? ? ?                ? acpi
-????????? ? ? ? ?                ? adduser.conf
```

To long list a directory **read** and **execute** permission is required for directory.

For below error just post `/etc/passwd` file entry for the id 1002

> I have no name!@vpn-server:/$ whoami
>
> whoami: cannot find name for user ID 1002

Answer (score 0):

If the permissions were set on `/etc` itself to be `644` then just type this:  `chmod 755 /etc`

If the permissions were set recursively...  you've got a much deeper problem than just that.

Comment: Yah, I don't have permissions to do that. Was chmod 644 /etc/ the same as chmod 644 /etc -r ?

Comment: No, it is not the same as `-R` (capital R).  If `-R` had been specified, it also would have hosed up pretty much any config file your system uses.  Fixing that would be nigh impossible to do correctly.  Since it's only `/etc`, just change the perms to `755` and you SHOULD be golden.